# Target tags in CSS, in Content-type application/xhtml+xml for earliers internet explorer

Tags: php, internet-explorer, xslt, xhtml, xml-namespaces

Below i try to target elements with tagname (span) in CSS, but it doesnt work in earliers internet explorer... if someone have a solution to this probleme please help...

index.php

```
<?php header('Content-type: application/xhtml+xml'); ?>

<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="copy.xsl"?>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:aa="zz" xmlns:ee="rr">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        /* it work */ aa\:span{background: #00ff00;}
        /* it doesnt work */ span{background: #00ff00;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <aa:span id="span1">
        <aa:p>aaa</aa:p>
    </aa:span>
    <ee:span id="span1">
        <ee:p>aaa</ee:p>
    </ee:span>
</body>
</html>
```

copy.xsl

```
<stylesheet version="1.0"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <template match="/">
        <copy-of select="."/>
    </template>
</stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you could transform all elements to plain HTML without namespace doing e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Then you need also need

```
<xsl:template match="@* | comment() | text() | processing-instruction()">
  <xsl:copy/>
</xsl:template>
```

to ensure other nodes are copied unchanged.

So all together you get

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="*">
      <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@* | comment() | text() | processing-instruction()">
      <xsl:copy/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for reaction, I just want to mention that I'm new in XSL, I replaced the content of copy.xsl with the first part of your answer, but I don't know where to inseret the second part of the code (Then you need also...)? or in general how to apply your response?

Comment: Someone could help and tell me how to proceed to apply the answer that @Martin Honnen posted...? I'm new in XSL :) so be patient please...

Comment: @kapsula, I have edited my answer to show you a complete stylesheet with the two templates.

Comment: thanks first, i'v insert the last code you'v posted, it throw me a message (XML Parsing Error: prefix not bound to a namespace
Location: *** Line Number 4, Column 5: ---^ <xsl:template match="*">) i'v added xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" now it throw me (Error loading stylesheet: Parsing an XSLT stylesheet failed.)

Comment: @kapsula, I am sorry, I had copied some code from your question to complete the stylesheet but that part did not fit together with my samples. Corrected now.

Comment: now it works :), but it seems like the css is not linked! and the span tags hase display:block! not inline (defult value)... should i change something in the php file?

Comment: I can't help with PHP, sorry. I don't see why a span would be treated as a block element after an XSLT transformation is applied. Your CSS in your sample is inline, so I am not sure why you say "the css is not linked".

Comment: sorry i misstated my last comment, I meant that the css style tag seems like is ignored...

Comment: Could the declaration (Content-type: application/xhtml+xml) causes me this problem?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have further time this weekend. If you want to apply CSS then I would first try with some plain HTML document delivered as text/html in standards mode which validates as HTML 4 or as HTML5. Then try to create the same valid document structure with your XSLT. Currently you have `p` elements inside `span` elements which is not valid and that might cause problems.

Comment: Yes right it was `p` tag in `span` that causes the problem! thanks Martin, now i think i'll post a new question, because in earliest internet explorer they told me if i want to download the file, i think the content type xhtml+xml does not supported by these browsers... thanks again...